# How to prove this integration is not zero

Tags: real-analysis, integration

Let {$f_{n}$}$_{n=1}^{\infty}$ be a sequence of non-zero elements of $L^{2}[0,1]$. Prove that there is a function $g\in L^{2}[0,1]$ such that for all $n\ge1$ we have $\int_{0}^{1}g(x)f_{n}(x)dx\neq0$.

I try to assume there isn't such function $g$ and get contradiction. But I couldn't find what's the contradiction. I can show all $f_{n}=0 \quad a.e$.

Maybe my idea is not correct and maybe we can construct a function $g$ satisfying $\int_{0}^{1}g(x)f_{n}(x)dx\neq0$.

Comment: If $f_n=0$ a.e., then $gf_n=0$ a.e., right...

Comment: Is there anything else given about $f_n$?

Comment: @Mark Viola No! There is not any assumption on $f_{n}$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that

$$U_n = \left\{ f\in L^2([0,1]) : \int_0^1 f f_n dx\neq 0 \right\}$$

is an nonempty (since $f_n$ is nonzero) open sets which is dense in $L^2 ([0,1])$. The Baire Category theorem says that

$$ \bigcap U_n$$

is nonempty. Thus there is $g\in L^2([0,1])$ so that

$$ \int_0^1 g f_n dx\neq 0$$

for all $n$.

Comment: Could you use other methods rather than Baire Category Theorem?

Comment: If each $f_n=0$ almost everywhere, then $gf_n=0$ almost everywhere and $\int gf_n\,dx=0$.

Comment: But they assume that each $f_n$ is non zero @mark

Comment: @ArcticChar Yes, that is true.  But they could be zero everywhere but on a set of measure $0$.

Comment: Then that would not be a nonzero element in $L^2(0,1)$, where two functions which agree almost everywhere are the same element in it. @markviola

Comment: By the phrase, "a nonzero element of $L^2$, do you mean an element such that $\int f^2\,dx\ne0$?

Comment: I interpret that literally: it is in $L^2$, and is not the zero element. @MarkViola. Of course one consequence is that $\int f^2 \neq 0$.

Comment: @ArcticChar I would have thought that a non-zero element of $L^2$ is any square integrable function that is not identically zero.